# Show that every real number lambda is an eigen value of L

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let S be the set of all sequences $$(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)$$ of real numbers. Consider the linear left-shift map: $$L:S \rightarrow S:L(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)=(x_2,x_3,x_4,...)$$

Show that every real number lambda is an eigenvalue of L.

The solution says that $$\vec{v} = (1,\lambda, \lambda^2, \lambda^3,...)$$ is an eigenvector: $$S(\vec{v})=\lambda\vec{v}$$.

Could someone explain what the question is asking and what the solution means? I'm not really sure how to arrive at this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $S \vec{v} = (\lambda, \lambda^2, \ldots) = \lambda (1, \lambda, \lambda^2, \ldots) = \lambda \vec{v}$, so $\vec{v}$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Since $\lambda$ was an arbitrary real number, every real number is an eigenvalue of $S$ with eigenvector $(1, \lambda, \lambda^2, \ldots) $.

Comment: Nevermind, I misread the question

Answer (score 0):

For proving the fact that every real number is an eigenvalue of $L$, you need to prove that for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a vector $v \in S$ such that $L(v) = \lambda v$.

So assume that $\lambda$ is given. You construct $v = (1, \lambda, \lambda ^2, \dots)$. It is clear that for this vector $L(v) = \lambda v$. Therefore, every real number is an eigenvalue for $L$.